# Optimize/losslessly compress images like the PageSpeed does

Tags: php

I compress the JPEG images as below:

```
function convert_img($img_source) {
    $img_destination = $img_source;
    $max_width = 150;
    $max_height = 150;
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_source);
    list($width,$height) = getimagesize($img_source);
    $x_ratio = $max_width/$width;
    $y_ratio = $max_height/$height;

    if ($width <= $max_width && $height <= $max_height) {
        $tn_width = $width;
        $tn_height = $height;
        } elseif ($x_ratio * $height < $max_height) {
            $tn_height = ceil($x_ratio * $height);
            $tn_width = $max_width;
        } else {
            $tn_width = ceil($y_ratio * $width);
            $tn_height = $max_height;
    }

    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_width,$tn_height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$tn_width,$tn_height,$width,$height);
    imagejpeg($tmp,$img_destination,80);
    imagedestroy($src);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
}
```

The problem is that I always get an image a little bit larger in size than PageSpeed suggests.

For example for an image with 8.85KB in size, PageSpeed suggests that I can reduce this size by 356B.

How do I compress my images and make them to have the smallest size possible? In order to make the PageSpeed to not suggest anything and to get 100 points.

Comment: Are you trying to optimise for an online validator? :-)

Comment: I am trying to get 100points in PageSpeed :)

Comment: I don't think 356 bytes are going to matter in the real world :-)

Comment: I know, but I want to see if is there a way to achieve it :) I am going to have larger images, and there would be a save in 10kb for each image.

Comment: If you want to compress a JPEG, be prepared to accept some quality loss. You can save a few bytes by stripping the meta-data but not 10k per image.

Comment: So maybe those 356B are the meta-data? Do you know how to strip it?

Answer (score 1):

Compression is only possible to the detriment of quality. The same is in music and video.

```
imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
```